# Read CSV with last column as array of values (and the values are inside parenthesis and separated by comma) in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I have a CSV file where the last column is inside parenthesis and the values are separated by commas. The number of values is variable in the last column. When I read them to as Dataframe with some column names as follows, I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match`. My CSV file looks like this

```
a1,b1,true,2017-05-16T07:00:41.0000000,2.5,(c1,d1,e1)
a2,b2,true,2017-05-26T07:00:42.0000000,0.5,(c2,d2,e2,f2,g2)
a2,b2,true,2017-05-26T07:00:42.0000000,0.5,(c2)
a2,b2,true,2017-05-26T07:00:42.0000000,0.5,(c2,d2)
a2,b2,true,2017-05-26T07:00:42.0000000,0.5,(c2,d2,e2)
a2,b2,true,2017-05-26T07:00:42.0000000,0.5,(c2,d2,e2,k2,f2)
```

what I finally want is something like this:

```
root
 |-- MId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsTeacher: boolean(nullable = true)
 |-- STime: datetype(nullable = true)
 |-- TotalMinutes: double(nullable = true)
 |-- SomeArrayHeader: array<string>(nullable = true)
```

I have written the following code till now:

```
val infoDF =
  sqlContext.read.format("csv")
    .option("header", "false")
    .load(inputPath)
    .toDF(
      "MId",
      "PId",
      "IsTeacher",
      "STime",
      "TotalMinutes",
      "SomeArrayHeader")
```

I thought of reading them without giving column names and then cast the columns which are after the 5th columns to array type. But then I am having problems with the parentheses. Is there a way I can do this while reading and telling that fields inside parenthesis are actually one field of type array.

Comment: that is not a proper csv content, the last column must be enclosed in double quotes.. you cant read arraytype with csv.. will check if there is any workaround

Comment: Yeah I know that. But my file looks like this only. If it was in quotes there would be no problem with csv-read but it's not in the quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. The solution is only tactical for your case. The below one worked for me

```
  val df = spark.read.option("quote", "(").csv("in/staff.csv").toDF(
    "MId",
    "PId",
    "IsTeacher",
    "STime",
    "TotalMinutes",
    "arr")
  df.show()
  val df2 = df.withColumn("arr",split(regexp_replace('arr,"[)]",""),","))
  df2.printSchema()
  df2.show()
```

**Output:**

```
+---+---+---------+--------------------+------------+---------------+
|MId|PId|IsTeacher|               STime|TotalMinutes|            arr|
+---+---+---------+--------------------+------------+---------------+
| a1| b1|     true|2017-05-16T07:00:...|         2.5|      c1,d1,e1)|
| a2| b2|     true|2017-05-26T07:00:...|         0.5|c2,d2,e2,f2,g2)|
| a2| b2|     true|2017-05-26T07:00:...|         0.5|            c2)|
| a2| b2|     true|2017-05-26T07:00:...|         0.5|         c2,d2)|
| a2| b2|     true|2017-05-26T07:00:...|         0.5|      c2,d2,e2)|
| a2| b2|     true|2017-05-26T07:00:...|         0.5|c2,d2,e2,k2,f2)|
+---+---+---------+--------------------+------------+---------------+

root
 |-- MId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IsTeacher: string (nullable = true)
 |-- STime: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TotalMinutes: string (nullable = true)
 |-- arr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+---+---+---------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+
|MId|PId|IsTeacher|               STime|TotalMinutes|                 arr|
+---+---+---------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+
| a1| b1|     true|2017-05-16T07:00:...|         2.5|        [c1, d1, e1]|
| a2| b2|     true|2017-05-26T07:00:...|         0.5|[c2, d2, e2, f2, g2]|
| a2| b2|     true|2017-05-26T07:00:...|         0.5|                [c2]|
| a2| b2|     true|2017-05-26T07:00:...|         0.5|            [c2, d2]|
| a2| b2|     true|2017-05-26T07:00:...|         0.5|        [c2, d2, e2]|
| a2| b2|     true|2017-05-26T07:00:...|         0.5|[c2, d2, e2, k2, f2]|
+---+---+---------+--------------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! What do quotes do there? I have huge files in GB, is there any performance issue with this?

Comment: "quote" is a feature in csv parser - when that quote character is appearing, the parser will read the contents upto the next quote character into a single column. Thus we are allowed to have delimiters in our data, provided they are surrounded by quote characters. The default quote character is "- double quotes. CSV parsers doesn't allow more than one character for the quote feature. In our case we have ( and ), so I gave "(" while reading and in df2, I removed the ")". We are lucky that this column is in the last, so it read till the end of the line.

Comment: So quote here will treat the default quotes (") as one of the quotes as well? And it will also treat "(" as one of the quote, is it?

Comment: in our case, we have overridden with "(", you can have only one quote character..